# getting the id from the listview when click on item , in another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

The code below give generate the ListView

```
public class MyList extends ListActivity {
static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {LONG LIST OF COUNTRIES};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.main,COUNTRIES));
    ListView lv=getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long id){
        Intent i=new Intent(MyList.this,Another.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                          b.putInt("id", (int)id);
                          intent.putExtras(b);
                          startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Another activity is

```
public class Another extends Activity{
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onCreate(icicle);
  setContentView(R.layout.mainseocnd);
  Bundle b=new Bundle();
  int value= b.getInt("id",0);
  TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
  tv.setText(""+value);  
  }
}
```

Now when i click on the any list item say id-5 it always display 0 
I want to get  the listview item id like if user click second item in list the another acivity should display 1(b/c start with 0).
please correct me where it is going wrong.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second activity instead of

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
int value= b.getInt("id",0);
```

use

```
int value = icicle.getInt("id",0);
```

This will give you a solution... :)

Comment: thanks problem get solved. for your effort your answer get accepted.

Comment: Just to make sure I get that right: This answer didn't solve your problem but you marked it as the correct solution anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Your way of retrieving the value is wrong:

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
int value= b.getInt("id",0);
```

You create a new bundle and try to get a value from it, when there is none *(it's new)*.
You have to get the extras supplied with the launch intent for that activity instead. Try

```
int value = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, but what I wanted to know out of curiosity (and clear for search engine users): Did that answer above really work for you? As far as I'm concerned the `savedInstanceState` and the launch intent extras are 2 different things, the only thing that they have in common is that they store their infos in a `Bundle`. E.g. you should get a NPE when that activity is launched for the first time.

Comment: actually i passed the value using intent.putExtra and got that value using getIntent(); and intent.getInt("id",0);